# Focus or open window in gnome on keyboard shortcut

Tags: gnome, wmctrl

As described here (askubuntu.com/questions/234206/shortcut-to-switch-to-app/328842) the `wmctrl` gives you access to your windows. So you can switch via keyboard. But I like to have one shortcut to open and focus if it is yet open.

Is there a tool for that?

Comment: Can you rephrase the question?  It's kind of confusing.  Just the last sentence please, "But I like to have one short...."

Comment: See prototype below. Works in terminal but not as a shortcut.

Comment: If you use Unity, you can just put the app on the launcher bar and press 'Super+X' where X is the character corresponding to the app's order in the launcher.  Press and hold the super key to see all the 'Super+X' possibilities

Comment: Nah, it's still gnome-shell. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Yet another solution.

Make sure you have wmctrl installed: `sudo apt install wmctrl`

Make a shortcut with the command: `bash -c "wmctrl -a chrome ; [ "$?" == "1" ] && google-chrome"`

Explanation: first we try to focus on chrome (`wmctrl -vxa chrome`), next we verify if we are successful "$?" == "0" or not "$?" == "1" and if not we then launch google chrome (`[ "$?" == "1" ] && google-chrome"`).

You also could make the shortcut `bash -c "wmctrl -a chrome || google-chrome"`

`||` means that if the first command fails, execute the second.

Answer (score 1):

I have the following directly as a keyboard shortcut:

```
#                Focus Chrome if it's running,           start it otherwise.
sh -c "if test $(wmctrl -vxa chrome 2>&1 | wc -l) -eq 1; then google-chrome; fi"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try these instructions (**tested**):

- First get *WM_CLASS* name of app `xprop | grep WM_CLASS`
- Then make shortcut `bash -c "wmctrl -xa <WM_CLASS> || <WM_CLASS>"`
- For example: `bash -c "wmctrl -xa google-chrome || google-chrome`

Answer (score 1):

1. make sure `wmctrl` is installed:

`sudo apt install wmctrl`

2. open the gnome `Settings`, then `Keyboard Shortcuts`. add this command:

`bash -c "wmctrl -a firefox || firefox"`

### Explanation:

`wmctrl` tries to open the window if it was open already. In this case the next command won't execute. But if the window was not already open the next command would execute and run the program/script you want (e.g. `firefox`).

#### PS:

This is the definition of `||` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Got it almost.

Created `/usr/local/bin/go` (`sudo vim /usr/local/bin/go`) with these lines:

```
#!/bin/bash

if wmctrl -l | grep -i --quiet "${1}"; then
    wmctrl -a ${1}
else
    ${1}
fi
```

Made it executable: `sudo chmod ugo+x /usr/local/bin/go`

And added some shortcuts to the system:

Name: `Firefox`
Command: `go firefox`
via Super+F

But firefox doesn't show up. Via console it act like it should.

Answer (score 0):

I used OlivierBlanvillain's approach but modified for a specific outcome:

I wanted <kbd>F12</kbd> to toggle between Chrome or my Terminal, depending on what was focused. I'm using [xdotool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/en/man1/xdotool.1.html) in addition to wmctrl.

```
if [[ $(xdotool getwindowfocus getwindowname) == *Google\ Chrome ]]; then wmctrl -a terminal; else wmctrl -a chrome; fi
```